# Embedding mRuby: retrieving mrb_parser_message after parse error

Tags: parsing, error-handling, embedding, mruby

I'm trying to embed mRuby in a [Max MSP](https://cycling74.com/products/max/#.WOKVlhjpPeQ) object. One of the first things I want to setup is error logging in the Max IDE console window. To that effect, after I parse the code ( stored in a C string ) with mrb_parse_string, I expect errors to be available in the parser's error_buffer array, but the structures in this array are always empty ( lineno and column set to 0 and message set to NULL ) even when there is an error.

Is there a special way to set up the parser before parsing the code so it fills its error_buffer array properly in case an error occurs ? I've looked into the mirb source, but it doesn't look like it. I'm lost. Here is the code I'm using, taken from a small C program I'm using as test:

```
mrb_state *mrb;
char *code;
struct mrb_parser_state *parser;

parser  = mrb_parse_string(mrb, code, mrbc_context_new(mrb));

if (parser->nerr > 0) {
  for(i = 0; i < parser->nerr; i++) {
    printf("line %d:%d: %s\n", parser->error_buffer[i].lineno,
                               parser->error_buffer[i].column,
                               parser->error_buffer[i].message);
  }

  return -1;
}
```

When passed the following faulty ruby code:

```
[1,1,1]]
```

the previous code outputs :

```
line 1:8: syntax error, unexpected ']', expecting $end
line 0:0: (null)
```

I don't know where the first line comes from, since I compiled mRuby with MRB_DISABLE_STDIO defined and as line 14 and following in mrbconf.md suggests, but it is accurate.

The second line is the actual output from my code and shows that the returned `mrb_parser_state` structure's `error_buffer` is empty, which is surprising since the parser did see an error.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry totally misunderstood your question.
So you want to:

1. capture script's syntax errors instead of printing.
2. make `MRB_DISABLE_STDIO` work.

For 1st issue

```
struct mrb_parser_state *parser;

parser  = mrb_parse_string(mrb, code, mrbc_context_new(mrb));
```

should be replaced with:

```
struct mrbc_context *cxt;
struct mrb_parser_state *parser;

cxt = mrbc_context_new(mrb);
cxt->capture_errors = TRUE;
parser  = mrb_parse_string(mrb, code, cxt);
```

[like what mirb does](https://github.com/mruby/mruby/blob/323121925ac87478d1f92dc1376557bc4785f589/mrbgems/mruby-bin-mirb/tools/mirb/mirb.c#L421-L424).

For 2nd issue I don't know your `build_config.rb` so I can't say much about it.
Some notes to make things accurate:

`MRB_DISABLE_STDIO` is a compile flag for building mruby so you need to pass it in `build_config.rb` like:

```
cc.defines << %w(MRB_DISABLE_STDIO)
```

(see [build_config_ArduinoDue.rb](https://github.com/mruby/mruby/blob/08a1dd2ac89333bd928a3300f712d1a7fb57e8ff/examples/targets/build_config_ArduinoDue.rb#L53))

<s>line 1:8: syntax error, unexpected ']', expecting $end</s>

is the parsing error of mruby parser(`[1,1,1]]` must be `[1,1,1]`).
And `1:8` means 8th column of 1st line (which points to unnecessary `]`) so it seems like your C code is working correctly to me.

(For a reference your code's compilation error in CRuby:
https://wandbox.org/permlink/KRIlW2956TnS6puD )

```
prog.rb:1: syntax error, unexpected ']', expecting end-of-input
[1,1,1]]
        ^
```

Comment: Maybe the question was not clearly stated. The error was expected and I know what the error output means. The question was twofolds : first, there should be no direct output on a regular stream from the parser, as I've compiled mRuby with MRB_DISABLE_STDIO defined and as line 14 and following of mrbconf.md suggest. Second, my code tries to explicitly capture the error message from the parser that, as far as I understand, should be available in the mrb_parser_state structure returned by mrb_parse_string, but it isn't. I edited the question to make it clearer ( I hope ).

Comment: @Jujule Updated the answer.

Comment: It works ! Thanks a lot ! What kills me is that I did read mirb source after greping the source for <code>error_buffer</code>. Apparently, enabling error capture also prevents the parser to output error message by itself, which removes the unwanted first output line. And thanks for explaining how to pass the compiler flag.